# q-analog of Stirling expansion.

Tags: calculus, q-analogs

It is well-known that $\ln\left(\Gamma(x)\right)=x\ln(x)-x+o(x)$.
Now consider a integer $q>1$ and $\theta>1$ a real number.
Can one write an asymptotic expansion (at least 2 terms) for
$$\ln\left(\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}|x-q^j|\right)\quad(n\to+\infty)$$
with $|x|=q^{n\theta}$ ($x\in\mathbb C$)?

Thanks in advance